# Get 'scale' in matplotlib quiver plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing a matplotlib quiver plot with the following command:

```
Q = quiver(X[::30,::30],Y[::30,::30],U[::30,::30],V[::30,::30],\
         units='x', color='#383838',width=0.004*nx*dx, \
           pivot='mid',headaxislength=5)
```

It mostly comes out fine, but I just need the arrows a bit shorter in length. Is there a way to know the value of the 'scale' that quiver is using to generate the plot, something like `Q.get_scale()`, so that I can tweak that value and get the length I want?